# How to return an array in java? Using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Heres what I have for the method:

```
public int[] generateNumbers(int numberOfTimes){
        int[] generatedNumbers = new int[numberOfTimes];
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < generatedNumbers.length){
            generatedNumbers[counter] = generator.nextInt(this.maxNumber - this.minNumber + 1) + this.minNumber;
            counter++;
        }
        return generatedNumbers;    
    }
```

I created a JUnit4 Test, and just to test its output, I have this:

```
@Test
    public void testGenerateNumbers() {
        assertEquals(this.simulator.generateNumbers(1), 2);
    }
```

Now, this returns false obviously, and the expected value was <[I@6f1d0b1>. Why am I getting a location instead of the actual array? Any help would be appreciated... By the way, we must use assertEquals, so anything else is out of the question, and yes I realize using something else to test this is easier.

Comment: You're comparing an array with an `int`, which is indeed wrong =\

Comment: `[I@6f1d0b1` is not a location. The `[` represents it's a 1-dimensional array. The `I` represents it's composed of integers and the `6f1d0b1` represents the hashcode for that array. Just a heads up :)

Comment: Yes, I realize this...however, I just wanted the return for the simulator. Don't really care about the 2, was only wondering why I was returning <[I@6f1d0b1>

Comment: Ohhhh all right, thanks Obicere!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `assertArrayEquals()`

```
assertArrayEquals(this.simulator.generateNumbers(1), new int[] {2});
```

Comment: Apparently `assertEquals` is the only kind of assertion the OP is allowed to use, which is a pretty bizarre constraint, IMO.

Comment: Oh. Figures it would be something like this. Thanks!

Comment: It's for a CS class. Our professor is very strict...I suppose this is TECHNICALLY assertEquals...

Answer (score 3):

> Why am I getting a location instead of the actual array?

You're getting the array (reference), but the error message is printing out the result of calling `toString()` on it. That's not terrible useful to you, unfortunately.

If you're actually trying to check the *length*, you need to do that:

```
assertEquals(1, simulator.generateNumbers(1).length);
```

Or to check the first value within the array:

```
assertEquals(2, simulator.generateNumbers(1)[0]);
```

(Note that the *expected* value comes first. It's really important to get the "expected" and "actual" order right in order to make the error messages sensible.)

Of course `assertArrayEquals` is the best approach here, but if you *really* need to use `assertEquals`, you could convert the array to a list:

```
assertEquals(Arrays.asList(new int[] { 2 }),
             Arrays.asList(simulator.generateNumbers(1)));
```

(It's not clear *why* `assertEquals` would be the only kind of assertion available to you... that's a very odd constraint.)

Answer (score 0):

If you *absolutely must* use `assertEquals` (I'd like to know why), you can do this:

```
assertEquals(true, Arrays.equals(new int[] { 2 }, this.simulator.generateNumbers(1)));
```